# Could anyone explain how my textbook did this simplification?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

The book is talking about proving Pascal's triangle increases until the middle, until which point it decreases.

[image]

Theorem 4.2 refers to the [Multiplicative formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula)

I just don't understand how that left side could simplify to $1$. And how do they rearrange it?

Comment: Should the $?$ be $=$s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numerator of the left side is $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$.

The numerator of the right side is $n(n-1) \cdots (n-k+1)(n-k)$.

Dividing both sides by $n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$, the left's numerator becomes $1$, while the right's numerator becomes $(n-k)$.

Similarly, the denominator on the left side is $k(k-1)\cdots 1$.

The denominator on the right side is $(k+1)k(k-1)\cdots 1$.

Multiplying both sides by $k(k-1)\cdots 1$, the left's denominator becomes $1$, while the right's denominator becomes $k+1$.

This results in: $1/1 = (n-k)/(k+1)$.

Does this clear things up?

Comment: Beautifully so. Thank you.

Comment: Ellipses often lead to confusion around terms that look like $n - k + 1$; when in doubt, try to write in an extra term on either side of the ellipses. This often (but definitely not always) clarifies things.